# Google account remove

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

So I found a phone and I can't use it because I don't have or know the Google account that us linked in with the phone. How do I go about removing the account. I've factory reset it and everything. Any solutions???

Comment: Sounds suspicious...

Comment: There is no linked account after factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Gmail app. Top left has 3 dots for menu, brings up folders and such. By the current login name there is an arrow which will open up an accounts option. Open it up, click on existing account, press the menu dots for it and click "remove account"